# Error Queuing Visual Studio Load Test on Remote Test Controller

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on my local workstation, connecting to my test controller hosted in Amazon's EC2 cloud (Windows 2008 Server R2).  I have added the EC2 elastic IP to my hosts file, and I can use the "Manage Controller" feature and see that the Agent is online.

My local Visual Studio is running with the same username and password as the test controller service account (via runas).

When I try to run the load test, I get the following error:

> Failed to queue test run 'xxx': The  requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

In my local event log, the following error is written.  It seems like a DNS resolution problem, but since I am able to connect to the controller, I am stumped as to what else to check.

```
(devenv.exe, PID 9160, Thread 18) ControllerProxy: Queue test run error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.FileCopyService.get_DeploymentFlags()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.<StartTestRun>b__d(FileCopyService fileCopyService)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.RemoteObjectContainer`1.InvokeAsRemoteUser(Action`1 invoke)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerExecution.StartTestRun(TestRun testRun, RemoteObjectContainer`1 fileCopyServiceContainer, RemoteObjectContainer`1 defaultListenerContainer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerObject.QueueTestRun(TestRun testRun, FileCopyService fileCopyService, IControllerEvents eventHandler)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.IControllerExecution.QueueTestRun(TestRun testRun, FileCopyService fileCopyService, IControllerEvents eventHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.QueueTestRunWorker(Object state)
```

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same issue. Did you find any solution or something in the meanwhile?

Comment: It seemed that most of these issues all resolved back to permission errors. I did not manage to solve this problem with any permission settings, but in the end I ran all agents and controllers using synchronized user names and passwords and that managed to get the tests working.